# How do I change content of the bootstrap-5 popover using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, popover

so i'm using bootstrap to create a popover, and I want to change the content of it through vanilla JavaScript by setting an Attribute "data-bs-content", it's changing in the code but the change is not visible on the site, and I do not have a clue what is going on, please help :). Maybe there is another way to change content of it using vanilla JS.

JS:

```
const score = document.querySelector(".score1");
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-none score1" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="Chance: 1 to 13 983 816" data-bs-trigger="hover">
example
</button>
```

Not so important line - just gives back a number from range of 0-6.

```
let x = randomArray.filter((n) => validArray.includes(n)).length;
    console.log(x);
```

The JS switch itself works just fine but the content is changing only in the code.

```
    switch (x) {
      case 6:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance: 1 to 13 983 816");
        break;
      case 5:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance: 1 to 54 201");
        break;
      case 4:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance: 1 to 1 024");
        break;
      case 3:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance: 1 to 57");
        break;
      case 2:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance: 1 to 7,5");
        break;
      case 1:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance: 1 to 2,4");
        break;
      case 0:
        score.setAttribute("data-bs-content", "Chance 1 to 2,3");
    }

    score.innerHTML = `You guessed ${x} numbers.`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You must initialize popovers before they can be used.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#enable-popovers) And rather than changing the HTML, you can get the popover instance instead and change its content in JavaScript.

Here's an example. It includes a `switch(x)` where `x` is a random number `0-6` just to show how it *could* work. I added comments on all the bits that are relevant. Should be straightforward to implement in your project.

```js
// Enables the Bootstrap popover instance
new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('#popover'), {
  title: 'Click the button',
  content: 'You can do it!',
  trigger: 'hover focus'
}); 

function changePopoverContent() {

  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
  
  let chance = "";
  switch (x) {
    case 6:
      chance = "Chance: 1 to 13 983 816";
      break;  
    case 5:
      chance = "Chance: 1 to 54 201";
      break;
    case 4:
      chance = "Chance: 1 to 1 024";
      break;
    case 3:
      chance = "Chance: 1 to 57";   
      break;
    case 2:
        chance = "Chance: 1 to 7,5";
      break;
    case 1:
        chance = "Chance: 1 to 2,4";
      break;
    case 0:
        chance = "Chance 1 to 2,3";
      break;      
  }
  
  // Returns a Bootstrap popover instance
  const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#popover') 

  // Set the content of the popover instance
  popover.setContent({
    '.popover-header': 'Popover title - ' + x,
    '.popover-body': chance
  }) 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" id="popover" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" onclick="changePopoverContent()">Click to change popover content</button>
```